# Web fonts not applied in Generated PDF using ephtmltopdf Library on server ii7

Tags: c#, css, pdf

We have used in external stylesheet

```
    @font-face 
{
    font-family: "MuseoSans100";
    src: url("MuseoSans_100-webfont.eot");      
    src: url("MuseoSans_100-webfont.eot?iefix") format("eot"), 
         url("MuseoSans_100-webfont.woff") format("woff"), 
         url("MuseoSans_100-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), 
         url("MuseoSans_100-webfont.svg#webfont") format("svg"); 
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;         
}
```

and in our html page I have given path of stylesheet.

The PDF file is displaying proper on my Local, Development Server and Test Server. But when we added the package on Preview site. We found one issue after the generated pdf above webfont not applied.

Comment: Could you provide the issue/problem?

Comment: By "ii7", do you mean IIS7?